# Defining entity in model

Tags: php, model, crud, atk4

I am trying to do a CRUD as mentioned in Jobeet tutorial(http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/tutorial/jobeet/day3). I have also added a generate.php inside page directory with the code mentioned in the link. When I try to access it via browser by http://localhost/atk4.1.2/?page=generate I am getting the following error,

```
Exception_ForUser
You should call parent::init() when you override it


Additional information: 

 - object_name: gift_project_generate

 - class: page_generate
```

I also have added a page named crud.php with the following contents inside the page directory the contents of which are as follows,

```
<?php
class page_crud extends Page{
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $tabs=$this->add('Tabs');
        $tabs->addTab('Gifts')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Gift');
    }
}
```

The following is the Gift.php inside the Model directory,

```
<?php
class Model_Gift extends Model_Table {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('id');
        $this->addField('name')->type('text');
        $this->addField('url')->type('text');
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access the crud page via http://localhost/atk4.1.2/?page=crud, I see the following errors,

```
Exception_InitError
You should define entity code for Model_Gift


C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib\BaseException.php:37
```

But the database already has a table named gift and `$this->dbConnect();` is not commented in Frontend.php.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your model definition:

```
public $enity_code='gift';
```

This should be exactly same as the name of your table in SQL.

The other error you are getting about init() not being called is a bug: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/22